Unable to load a jks file using PyJKS
Using Python 3.8.10, I am struggling to get a JKS file loaded in Python using pyjks.
As a note: this code is being executed with sudo when called.
keystore_file = 'file_name_here'
keystore_password = 'password'  

try:
    keystore = jks.KeyStore.load(keystore_file, keystore_password)
    print("Successfully loaded the keystore.")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Failed to load JKS keystore: {e}")
    sys.exit(1)

Output: Failed to load JKS keystore: Attempted "__index__" operation on ASN.1 schema object
Things I have tried so far:

Created a fresh SSL cert, converted via: keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore KEYSTORE.keystore -srcstoretype PKCS12 -destkeystore KEYSTORE.jks -deststoretype JKS -deststorepass PASSWORD -srcstorepass PASSWORD.

